# bat file to open an exex file and fire some commands in it

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I want to open my mql.exe file from bat file and fire some commands in it.
I have tried the same with below commands but its not working.
mql.exe is having command prompt UI.

The code that i wrote in my bat file is as follows :

```
CD E:\sqMql.exe
START sqMql.exe /K set cont user creator;
```

but i am not able to perform the same, manually i have to follow below steps to do the same.
1. open sqMql.exe
2. type set cont user creator; and then hit enter
3. type verbose on; and then hit enter

please let me knoe how can i automate this ?

Comment: what happens when you run the .bat file? Tip: add a "pause" to see what's wrong. From here, I could suggest to use "cd /D" instead of cd to switch drive, and also protect "set cont user ..." by quotes.

Comment: i am getting an error as below C:\Users\SOA2>CD E:\sqMql.exe
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\SOA2>START sqMql.exe /K set cont user creator;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming sqMql.exe takes keyboard input you could put the actual keyboard input in somefile.txt and do this:

```
sqMql.exe < somefile.txt
```

Updated because of stupid typo: You have to read FROM a file (<) not to write INTO a file (>)

Comment: Getting below error C:\Users\SOA2>CD E:\sqMql.exe
The directory name is invalid.

C:\Users\SOA2>START sqMql.exe  1>C:\Users\SOA2\Desktop\mql.txt

Comment: had a typo. try again :)

Comment: you cannot cd to an exe... Try `cd \D E:\` instead then start sqMql.exe